# When updating Next.js v10.1.13 to webpack5, getting warnings Can't resolve 'fsevents' in chokidar

Tags: next.js, webpack-5

`npm install next react react-dom` And running Node.js v12

Created most simple `pages/index.tsx`

```js
export default function PageHome(props) {
  return <>Hello World!</>
}
```

(I also had TypeScript configured as per [Next.js instructions](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript) but not sure if that's making a difference.)

```
C:\GitHub\reproduce-nextjs-webpack5-error>npm run dev
...
event - compiled successfully
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Can't resolve 'fsevents' in 'C:\GitHub\reproduce-nextjs-webpack5-error\node_modules\next\node_modules\chokidar'
<w> while resolving 'fsevents' in C:\GitHub\reproduce-nextjs-webpack5-error\node_modules\next\node_modules\chokidar to a directory
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Can't resolve 'fsevents' in 'C:\GitHub\reproduce-nextjs-webpack5-error\node_modules\next\node_modules\chokidar'
<w> while resolving 'fsevents' in C:\GitHub\reproduce-nextjs-webpack5-error\node_modules\next\node_modules\chokidar to a directory
```

Self-answered solution below for future readers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Upgrade Node.js
2. Delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`
3. Run `npm install` again
4. It works

   - Apparently something doesn't install when you run with an older Node.js version.
   - My `package.json` looked like

     ```json
     {
       "scripts": {
         "dev": "next dev",
         "build": "next build",
         "start": "next start"
       },
       "dependencies": {
         "next": "^10.1.3",
         "react": "^17.0.2",
         "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
       },
       "devDependencies": {
         "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
         "typescript": "^4.2.4"
       }
     }
     ```
   - The same `package.json` will install slightly differently switching from Node.js v12 to Node.js v15 as I just observed. This is why you have to complete not just step 1, but also steps 2 & 3.

Before:

```
C:\GitHub\reproduce-nextjs-webpack5-error>node --version
v12.4.0

C:\GitHub\reproduce-nextjs-webpack5-error>npm run dev

> @ dev C:\GitHub\reproduce-nextjs-webpack5-error
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: future.webpack5 option enabled https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
event - compiled successfully
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Can't resolve 'fsevents' in 'C:\GitHub\reproduce-nextjs-webpack5-error\node_modules\next\node_modules\chokidar'
<w> while resolving 'fsevents' in C:\GitHub\reproduce-nextjs-webpack5-error\node_modules\next\node_modules\chokidar to a directory
```

After:

```
C:\GitHub\reproduce-nextjs-webpack5-error>node --version
v15.14.0

C:\GitHub\reproduce-nextjs-webpack5-error>npm run dev

> dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: future.webpack5 option enabled https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
event - compiled successfully
event - build page: /
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled successfully
```

Yay! No warnings!

While there are comments below about future changes in `nextjs@canary`, the above examples worked for me with versions listed.

Comment: Actually, they said this is only an issue in Next.js v10.1.3. As of this writing, nextjs@canary has a fix.

Comment: Which one of the nextjs@canary?

Comment: FYI, this fix didn't work for me with `"next": "^10.1.3",` but node v14. Do you have a link to an issue in the NextJS repo?

Comment: Their comment was here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/24037#event-4592124968 _"The fsevents error has been solved on `next@canary` already. Please try upgrading."_

Answer (score 4):

Delete the .next folder and re-run `npm run dev`.
This happens when your system shuts down unexpectedly without saving.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this problem by killing all node processes on my production server.