# getting webpack warning during npm run dev and first load in Next.js

Tags: webpack, next.js, react-query

I am getting warning in Next.js from webpack. It's just showing warning but cause not any error.
The warning is like this:

```
[webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Node.js doesn't offer a (nice) 
 way to introspect the ESM dependency graph yet.
```

[image]

I'm using

- Next.js 10.1.3 with typescript (webpack 5 is enabled)
- react-query 3.13.11
- some basic api routes 
   
  my index.tsx file is like this:

```
const User = ({ userList }) => {

  const [ userId, setUserId] = useState('1');

  const { data, status } = useQuery(['user', userId], async ()=> {
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userId}`);
    return res.json();
  }, {
    staleTime: Infinity,
    cacheTime: Infinity
  } );

  return (
      <input type="number" onChange={e=>setUserId(e.target.value)} />
  )
};

export const getStaticProps = async (ctx) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  return {
    props: {
      userList: data
    }
  }
}
```

and _app.tsx file like this:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient()

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return(
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}
```

Please help me to understand this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67082806/when-updating-next-js-v10-1-13-to-webpack5-getting-warnings-cant-resolve-fsev this one helped me

Answer (score 2):

I was able to add a `next.config.js` file with the following and it suppressed the message. See next docs https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5

```
module.exports = {
  future: {
    webpack5: true,
  },
}
```

Comment: the only other thing I could say trying is, deleting your .next folder and restarting the server.

Comment: your comment is the correct approach.